# Handling line-breaks across XML/HTML/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, newline, line-breaks

I'm loading an XML file with ajax, dynamically writing/reading values to/from HTML form textareas using jQuery, and then saving back to an XML file by passing it to a PHP-write function on a form submit.

What I'm looking for is a consistent way to handle line-breaks and paragraphs across HTML/jQuery/XML-  Something where users would see actual line-breaks, not code, in html and form fields.

Up until now I've been using `<br/>` tags in CData fields in XML, but these show up in form fields, and jQuery is making a mess of my CData writes.

Any good ideas?  Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use actual return characters in the text, then in order to make them show up when displaying as HTML, you could set the css property `white-space:pre` or `white-space:pre-line`.

Answer (score 1):

unless i misunderstand the question, php has the built-in functions. nl2br($string); and br2nl($string);  you could save the data with nl2br and then load it normally everywhere except the text areas. load to the text area using br2nl($string);

Comment: @Johhny- I'm loading file dynamically- need jQuery functions, not PHP ones

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regex to switch out the `<br />` for `\n` and `\r` when writing to the form fields.

Comment: regexing text when going from one platform to another is always an option, but not the solution I'm hoping for.  I'm looking for a consistent way of handling line-breaks that WONT require me to transform the text each time- or if it's impossible, I need to know..